# How to open Firefox from Javascript

Tags: javascript, shell, firefox, command-line

How could i open firefox with specific page in javascript code ? is it possible ?

i saw that we can open firefox from command line, and we call this commande line from javascript via Shell function. but what i need is to open a specific page in firefox (with URL).

Thanks for your help

Comment: JavaScript running ***where***? A browser? NodeJS? SilkJS? WSH? JVM+Rhino/Nashorn?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: yes in a browser (Internet explorer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function executeCommands(inputparms)
   {

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");     
var commandtoRun ="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";
oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,inputparms,"", "open", "1");
```

}

Comment: I don't understand why he was downvoted on his own question. He posted his solution. Of course we all would have wanted something that works in every browser. His question was not specific on IE but that's what he wanted. We should encourage people to post their solution.I upvote him and I post a link on a shorter solution : http://forums.asp.net/t/1652038.aspx?How+can+we+force+a+link+to+open+a+URL+in+a+different+browser+

Answer (score -2):

Well if you want to open a new window you can do it by `Window.open()` method
here is the link [check out](http://jsbin.com/kecicarumu/1/edit?html,js,output) but if the browser is not working and you want to open whole browser by typing a js program on system not in browser you cannot do this.
Javascript works on browser only.
you can use command line in browser and simply type `window.open("https://google.com","",width=800,height=600)` and it will do the trick.
in order to open browser console go to tools tab in your browser and open developer tools>javascript console if you are using firefox simply press ctrl+shift+k 
But if you want to open firefox from ie. by reaching the system shell it is not possible by javascript the kingdom of js is limited by browser you cannot reach system.

Comment: Could i run command line from javascript ? then from this command line i open firefox with specified page. ?

Comment: updated the code with how you can reach js console in browser @SiMoKassab

Comment: Thanks for you answer, actually am using IE, and from IE want to open specified page in Firefox.

Comment: ah now everything is more clear you want to reach system shell with javascript but theres no way for this unfortunately javascript has no rights to reach system in ie by using activex you can reach files but this is what you can do maximum about the computer the kingdom of javascript is just within the browser @SiMoKassab